# How to integrate Chrome & Firefox browser into AutoHotKey

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, autohotkey

Is there a way to integrate `Chrome` and `Firefox` with `AutoHotKey` like Internet Explorer as below?

```
Gui Add, ActiveX, w980 h640 vWB,s.Explorer ;Whatever we give here instead 
;'s' I notice it loads IE control only. Someone in AHK forum
;said mentioning Mozilla instead 's' will load MozillaClass. That is false.
WB.Silent := True
WB.Navigate("https://www.google.com/")
Gui, Show,,Browsers in AHK GUI
Return
GuiClose:
Exitapp
Return
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you first install the Mozilla ActiveX Control on your system?  See http://www.iol.ie/~locka/mozilla/control.htm and, of course, Firefox?

Then, the line is:

```
Gui Add, ActiveX, w980 h640 vWB, Mozilla.Browser
```

Check out https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=31745 for more info.

Comment: I  checked it. It seems old and the last update was on 15/12/2005. The reason I want to use `firefox` or `chrome` is that these browsers support many features include html5. And I got the script from the same location you mentioned 'Check out'